Why is my Spring Boot repository and Hibernate returning stale data after updating an entity?
In simple words, I'm updating a Hibernate Table and simultaneous iterations and queries are loading a stale value.
I'm experiencing an issue with stale data in my Spring Boot application. Specifically, the query is returning outdated data immediately after updating an entity using a native query.
Here's the code for the email state service class, current email state repository and entity classes:
public class EsignEmailStateService {
    private final CurrentEsignEmailStateRepository currentEmailStateRepository;
    private final EsignEmailStateFactory emailStateFactory;

    public CurrentEsignEmailState getCurrentState() {
        if(!currentEmailStateRepository.existsByEnvelopeId("contractEnvelope1")){
            currentEmailStateRepository.save(CurrentEsignEmailState.builder()
                    .envelopeId("contractEnvelope1")
                    .build());
        }
        CurrentEsignEmailState stateObject  = currentEmailStateRepository.findByEnvelopeId("contractEnvelope1");
        return stateObject;
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Transactional
    public void nextState() {
        CurrentEsignEmailState currentEsignEmailState = getCurrentState();
        EsignEmailState currentState = emailStateFactory.createState(currentEsignEmailState.getCurrentState());
       
        EsignEmailState newCurrentState = currentState.nextState(); 

        saveCurrentState(newCurrentState.getClass().getSimpleName(), currentState.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    @Transactional
    private void saveCurrentState(String newstate, String oldstate) {
        currentEmailStateRepository.updateCurrentState("contractEnvelope1", newstate);
    }
}


@Repository
@Cacheable(value = false)
public interface CurrentEsignEmailStateRepository extends JpaRepository<CurrentEsignEmailState, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * from current_envelope_email_state where envelope_id = :envelopeId", nativeQuery = true)
    CurrentEsignEmailState findByEnvelopeId(@Param("envelopeId") String contractEnvelopeId);

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "update current_envelope_email_state set current_state = :state where envelope_id = :envelopeId", nativeQuery = true)
    void updateCurrentState(@Param("envelopeId") String contractEnvelopeId,@Param("state") String state);

    boolean existsByEnvelopeId(String contractEnvelopeId);
}

public class CurrentEsignEmailState {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String envelopeId;

    private String currentState;

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(){
        this.currentState = "StartState";
    }//Set message and body here
}

Here's the Spring Boot project which I have created to reproduce the issue and I've also added steps for reproduction:
Hibernate Stale Data Issue Repository
When calling the API the state machine will be triggered all at once and there we can see the update query is updating the entity in database but when we are fetching the newly updated entity it is giving the old data (which we can see in the console logs).
Via debugging, I can confirm that the database has the correct information and when the query runs, it returns the old data.
I've tried several methods, including using entityManager.flush(), entityManager.clear(), @Cacheable(false) in the repository class and disabling second level cache in hibernate, but the problem persisted.
If I add entityManager.flush(), entityManager.clear() in the saveCurrentState method it throws me the error:
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.example.StaleDataIssue.entities.ContractEnvelope#contractEnvelope1] - no Session

Here's the log which shows that the second level cache is disabled
2024-06-06T12:28:28.085+05:30  INFO 9160 --- [main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled

Can anyone help?

The issue is while using the update native query the data is updated in the database but the hibernate' s cache in the application is not updating the data in it.
I tried using the simple approach for updating the entity by doing this:
CurrentEsignEmailState currentEsignEmailState = currentEmailStateRepository.findByState(oldstate);
currentEsignEmailState.setCurrentState(newstate);
currentEmailStateRepository.saveAndFlush(currentEsignEmailState);

And this worked.
However, when I tested the update query on a simple project, it worked as intended. I'm not sure where the issue is.
